# How to scope static class object for specific background task?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, hangfire, background-task

Considering

```
public class BackgroundJob{
   public string jobName{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

AppConfig.cs

```
public class AppConfig{
   public static BackgroundJob currentJob{get;set;}
}
```

BackgroundjobService.cs

```
public interface IBackgroundJobService
{ ... }

public class BackgroundJobService : IBackgroundJobService
{
    private readonly ServiceScopFactory _serviceScopFactory;
    public BackgroundJobService(ServiceScopFactory serviceScopFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopFactory = serviceScopFactory;
    }
    public async Task RunBackgroundJobTest1()
    {
        using (var serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            AppConfig.currentJob = new(){ jobName = "job1" };

                var idx = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 100)
                {
                    idx++;
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"===> jobName = {currentJob.jobname}");
                }
        }
    }

    public async Task RunBackgroundJobTest2()
    {
        using (var serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            AppConfig.currentJob = new(){ jobName = "job2" };

                var idx = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 100)
                {
                    idx++;
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"===> jobName = {currentJob.jobname}");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Execute:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
   private readonly IBackgroundJobClient _backgroundJobClient; //hangfire
   public TestController(IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient)
   {
      _backgroundJobClient = backgroundJobClient;
   }
   [HttpGet("test")]
   public IActionResult Test()
   {
       _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IBackgroundJobService>(x=>x.RunBackgroundJobTest1()); //log ===> jobName = job2
       _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IBackgroundJobService>(x=>x.RunBackgroundJobTest2()); //log ===> jobName = job2
   }
}
```

As result, `AppConfig.currentJob` does not keep the first value from/inside `ServiceScop1` but it was reinitialized by the last task inside `ServiceScope2`

**Question:** pls anyone suggest me for correct implementation for this purpose?
 And it would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: _How to scope static class object for specific background task_ - Don't use `static` but create new instance for every scope.

Comment: You _might_ solve it using `[ThreadStatic]` but this will make bugs hard to find if the task scheduler runs jobs serially on the same thread. You're asking for correct implementations, but I think your `BackgroundJobService` should be subject to scrutiny as well. Why do you roll your own and not use [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Comment: @Fabio thanks for fast response, but we need to use it as global, means other service get called inside serviceScope can access this ```object``` too, without passing as parmeter to those which get called.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you sir. As my knowledge of background job for long running task is still in limit, I have read about using ServiceScopeFactory before you told me about, IHostedService.
Sure, I need correct implementation, and I'm glad for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not clear to me. Anyway, as I understand your question, you could try the code below.
It will make currentJob local to your processing. Unlike [ThreadStatic], this will not fail if the process changes thread :

```
public class AppConfig{
   private static System.Threading.AsyncLocal<BackgroundJob> _currentJob {get;} 
        = new System.Threading.AsyncLocal<BackgroundJob>();

 public static BackgroundJob currentJob {
     get {return _currentJob.Value;}
     set {_currentJob.Value = value;}
  }   
}
```

Note that this behaviour is not linked to the ScopeServiceFactories. To have full dependency injection, linked to the scope you would need to drop the statics.

Comment: Thank you! and we are sorry for a bit late response your answer.
For the question, that is we are testing for long running task, while running we thought we should store ```objects``` in current running scope ```global object``` as ```jobName```, ```userId```, ...  
and use this information in every service get called inside the ```scope```, whould be like ```AppConfig.currentJob.jobname```, ```.userId```, due to some table needed to flag user log info.

Comment: We have tested this solution already and it does work. but to be guarrenteed this behaviour is correct as our need or not, our knowledge still in limit . We have tried ```IHostedService``` as the comments on the question. 
But your answer does help us, thanks very much.

Comment: @sambath999: If you need it *for logging*, then I recommend `ILogger.BeginScope`.